# Is it possible to return files for server methods in hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to use `reply.file` (http://hapijs.com/api#replyfilepath-options) for a `server.method` (http://hapijs.com/api#servermethodname-fn-options), but it says that my `next` function doesn't have `file`:

```
Debug: hapi, internal, implementation, error
    TypeError: Uncaught error: Object function (err, result) {

                methodNext(err, result, null, { msec: timer.elapsed(), error: err });
            } has no method 'file'
    at /Users/user/Work/Dev/export.js:37:12
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Work/Dev/node_modules/webshot/lib/webshot.js:221:9)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
```

I have the following:

```
server.method('getExport', function(reqParams, queryParams, hostUri, next) {

  // ...
  next.file(filePath, {
    // Download as an attachment
    mode: 'attachment'
  });

});


Instance.server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/export',
  config: {
    handler: function(req, reply) {
      var uri = req.server.info.uri;

      server.methods.getExport(
        req.params,
        req.query,
        uri,
        reply
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Is it possible?

I'm using hapi v6.9.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method you have to pass it a callback method.  https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/83201d29bcc8c8edc46d9ecf4f1d51b7f3a3a4ff/lib/methods.js#L64

This is your code working:

```
var hapi = require('hapi'),
    server = new hapi.Server('0.0.0.0', 5000);

server.method('getExport', function(reqParams, queryParams, hostUri, reply, next) {

  // ...
  reply.file('/tmp/test.js', {
    // Download as an attachment
    mode: 'attachment'
  });

  next();

});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/export',
  config: {
    handler: function(req, reply) {
      var uri = req.server.info.uri;

      server.methods.getExport(
        req.params,
        req.query,
        uri,
        reply,
        function () {
            console.log('ran');
        }
      );
    }
  }
});

server.start()
```

I would highly suggest not using a server method for this, seems like overkill for replying with a file. I would also highly suggest upgrading to the latest version of hapi if possible.